# ¿Cómo puedo llamar un void dentro de un botón?

Tags: java, netbeans, filtro, busqueda

Buenas tardes muchachos/as, tengo un inconveniente, estoy tratando de adaptar un código de búsqueda con KeyReleased en java a mi proyecto pero hay algo que no he logrado hacer, agradecería un montón cualquier comentario que me pudiera ayudar.

```
void mostrartablaequipos17(String valor) {

    DefaultTableModel modelo17 = new DefaultTableModel();
    modelo17.addColumn("ID");
    modelo17.addColumn("ciudad");
    modelo17.addColumn("area");
    modelo17.addColumn("tipo_equipo");
    modelo17.addColumn("marca_equipo");
    modelo17.addColumn("modelo_equipo");
    modelo17.addColumn("nombre_equipo");
    modelo17.addColumn("no_serie_equipo");
    modelo17.addColumn("placa_inventario");
    modelo17.addColumn("uso_equipo");
    modelo17.addColumn("usuario_responsable");
    modelo17.addColumn("ubicacion_empresa");

    tablaequipossacama.setModel(modelo17);

    String sql = "";

    sql = "SELECT * FROM planilla_hoja_de_vida WHERE ciudad ='Sacama'";

    String datos[] = new String[43];
    Statement st;
    try {
        st = cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            datos[0] = rs.getString(1);
            datos[1] = rs.getString(2);
            datos[2] = rs.getString(3);
            datos[3] = rs.getString(4);
            datos[4] = rs.getString(5);
            datos[5] = rs.getString(6);
            datos[6] = rs.getString(7);
            datos[7] = rs.getString(9);
            datos[8] = rs.getString(10);
            datos[9] = rs.getString(30);
            datos[10] = rs.getString(39);
            datos[11] = rs.getString(40);

            modelo17.addRow(datos);
        }
        tablaequipossacama.setModel(modelo17);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(tablas_municipios.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Tengo este código que es de mi tabla de la BD, y necesito llamar el defaultablemodel llamado modelo17 acá en este otro código, que esta dentro del evento del jbutton.

```
buscar17.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){

      @Override
      public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {

        trs.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)"+buscar17.getText(), 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12));
      }
  });
trs = new TableRowSorter(modelo17);
tablaequipossacama.setRowSorter(trs);

}
```

En la parte que dice modelo17 pero dice que el tipo void no puede estar ahí, que puedo hacer, gracias.

Comment: Pues lo que tendrás que hacer es definir tu variable `modelo17` en un lugar visible en ambas funciones. Si la función `mostrartablaequipos17` y el listener que añades a `buscar17` están en la misma clase, puedes definir la variable como miembro de la clase y podrás acceder a ella en cualquier método de esa clase. Antes de hacer cosas tan complicadas, sin saber sobre el ámbito de las variables, te recomiendo volver al manual de Java y hacer ejemplos más básicos hasta que los tengas claros.

Comment: hola, gracias por responder a mi consulta, el listener es un codigo que trato de acoplar al mio, como puedo definir las variables como miembro de la clase?

Comment: Tienes que declararla fuera de cualquier metodo y dentro de la clase. Casi siempre se declaran abajo del nombre de la clase. Ej: public class Clase{ private int variableMiembro;...etc.}

Comment: @Julioenriquegodoymuñoz lo intento pero sigue sin funcionarme incializo la variable dentro del boton pero no funciona tampoco

Comment: Parece que tienes mal la clase interna, ya que yo siempre he visto que cuando declaran una clase interna lo hacen llamando  a una interface (KeyListener)y no a una clase adaptadora como key adapter. Prueba cambiando "new KeyAdapter(){}"  por "new KeyListener(){}"

Comment: No entiendo como pretendes hacer ningún programa sin saber cómo se declara una variable miembro de una clase. Bueno, sí, a base de que te lo terminen haciendo aquí.

Comment: bueno he aprendido empiricamente, talves se hacerlo pero no con el nombre que le dan, si ves que no puedes aportar un comentario constructivo sin una critica, no lo hagas.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia la clase adaptadora por una clase anonima interna y deberia funcionarte el boton

```
        buscar17.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
             trs.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("?i)"+buscar17.getText(),1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12));
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

       });
```

Ademas tienes que importar estas clases

```
            import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
            import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void buscar17KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                  
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    buscar17.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
         trs.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(buscar17.getText(),1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11));
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

   });
    trs = new TableRowSorter(modelo17);
    tablaequipossacama.setRowSorter(trs);


}
```

esto es lo que me sale aun la variable modelo17 del defaulttablemodel no he podido establecerla, por que no se como hacerlo :(